# TypeScript: accessing type information at runtime

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

If one creates dynamic properties based on parameter inputs:

```js
type ObjBuilder<Prop1 extends string, Prop2 extends string> = {
  [P in Prop1 | Prop2]: P extends Prop2  ? ()=>boolean : ()=>string
}

function objectBuilder<Prop1 extends string, Prop2 extends string>(
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
) : ObjBuilder<Prop1, Prop2> {
  return {
    [prop1]: () => true,
    [prop2]: () => prop2,
  } as ObjBuilder<Prop1, Prop2>
}

// note the duplication of information in this code
const a = objectBuilder<'p1', 'p2'>('p1', 'p2')

console.log(a.p1()) // true
console.log(a.p2()) //'p2'
```

Is it possible to access the type definitions in the function definition to avoid the duplication of `objectBuilder<'p1', 'p2'>('p1', 'p2')` and rather only have `objectBuilder<'p1', 'p2'>()` with the compiled javascript having access to the strings `p1` and `p2`?

In other words, have the JavaScript somehow via reflection access the type information and make it available at runtime?

[code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20220104&ssl=17&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwEIFcCWAbAJhATgHgAVcB7MARiggA9gIA7LAZyieFzXoHMAaKYsgCYqtBs1btOXAHxQAvFADeAKChQA2oSid+pClAA+uoQF0AXPxF1GLAWGFQA-FAAUASjnS4JEhggBDeigLd082Dm5lAF9lZQAzFHoAY2A0EiCSRAgU1EwcAjtKGmtxcKk+O2FisRYy7mkXVSgwPXILOt4mlqF2yW4eZTdg2ERc7DwiVoq9QVkVNVwIYBRcIPm1DW6Kc1chzyh2FAgBjc2Znfd5WS3BE6goqH8WeGR0cYKp43tpaNik9LYj3kUEyCGywDG+XwAHIKNC+LDBNCGrDyPCoIjoW5lP96ExfBAAHQYEhcFz+QkUdzY3H4vzE0nkymCalAA)

Comment: No, it is not possible. Try [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVgPqm). It is possible to infer arguments type so you don't need to explicitly use `<'p1', 'p2'>`

Comment: @captain-yossarian - thank you, yes that's a good solution as it also removes the duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can infer literal type of arguments.

COnsider this example:

```js
type ObjBuilder<Prop1 extends string, Prop2 extends string> = {
  [P in Prop1 | Prop2]: P extends Prop2 ? () => boolean : () => string
}

function objectBuilder<Prop1 extends string, Prop2 extends string>(
  prop1: Prop1,
  prop2: Prop2,
): ObjBuilder<Prop1, Prop2> {
  return {
    [prop1]: () => true,
    [prop2]: () => prop2,
  } as ObjBuilder<Prop1, Prop2>
}

const a = objectBuilder('p1', 'p2')
console.log(a.p1())
console.log(a.p2())
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVgPqm)

As you might have noticed, I have used `Prop1` and `Prop2` generics as an argument type instead of `string`. In this way TS is able to infer literal type.

If you are interested in this topis (function arguments type inference) you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)